# coredns crashes with error "Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/****: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, coredns

CoreDNS pod is not running. Please find below status.

```
kubectl get po --all-namespaces -o wide | grep -i coredns
kube-system            coredns-6955765f44-8qhkr                    1/1     Running            0          24m     10.244.0.59      k8s-master          <none>           <none>
kube-system            coredns-6955765f44-lpmjk                    0/1     Running            0          24m     10.244.1.43      k8s-worker-node-1   <none>           <none>
```

Please find below logs of pod.

```
kubectl logs coredns-6955765f44-lpmjk -n kube-system



E0420 03:43:03.855622       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
E0420 03:43:03.855622       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
E0420 03:43:03.855622       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
E0420 03:43:03.855622       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
E0420 03:43:05.859525       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
E0420 03:43:05.859525       1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
```

Comment: have you installed a cni such as flannel or calico?

Comment: where is the kubernetes deployed? local using Minikube or public cloud ?

Comment: I have installed flannel pod network to the cluster and 2 nodes of kubernetes cluster deployed using kubeadm locally on virtual machines.

Comment: When running `kubeadm init` did you specify correct pod cidr for flannel? Did you also try to flush the iptables?

Comment: I have flushed iptables on all nodes and deleted both coredns. Now both coredns pods showing healthy. I am not getting exactly why logs showing no route to the host before iptable flush as I was able to telnet to the ClusterIP on port 443. If iptable causing for this then which iptable rule should I apply to resolve this permanently.

Comment: What OS do you use? Do you still have logs from coredns pod deployed on master node  and could you share it?

Comment: After Iptable flush coredns working fine. I have deployed kubernetes cluster on CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core). Please find below logs of coredns pod which is running on master node.


`W0425 03:08:20.743295       1 reflector.go:302]   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98:      watch of *v1.Namespace ended with: too old resource version: 355230 (566639)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve `no route to host` issue with CoreDNS pods you have to flush iptables by running:

```
systemctl stop kubelet
systemctl stop docker
iptables --flush
iptables -tnat --flush
systemctl start kubelet
systemctl start docker
```

Also mind that flannel has been removed from the list of CNIs in the [kubeadm documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/commit/f73647531dcdade2327412253a5f839781d57897/):

> The reason for that is that Cluster Lifecycle have been
>   getting a number of issues related to flannel (either in kubeadm or
>   kops tickets) and we don't have good answers for the users as the
>   project is not actively maintained.
>   - Add note that issues for CNI should be logged in the respective issue
>   trackers and that Calico is the only CNI we e2e test kubeadm against.

So recommended approach would be also move to Calico CNI.

Answer (score 1):

I was using K8s 1.19.7 with flannel without any error, As soon as I upgraded to 1.21.1 it start showing above mentioned error and following fix works for me

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-source=10.244.0.0/16
firewall-cmd --reload
```